# How to say "you should search for x here"

Tags: grammar

I'm mostly a beginner and still figuring grammar out. I was wondering if

**(location)に (object)を さがしたほうがいい**

would be a grammatically correct format for a rough translation of "you should search for x here" in casual speech. for example,

**ウールマートに　りんごを さがしたほうがいい**

Thanks!

Comment: What is ウールマート？

Comment: Probably this? https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AB%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In everyday conversations, the location marker for the verb 「探{さが}す」 is 「で」 rather than 「に」.

Using 「に」 is not incorrect, but it surely would make the sentence sound (unnecessarily) literary, old-fashioned, poetic, etc.  Thus, I would not recommend that you use 「に」 in your sentence **unless you actually intend to use it for your own aesthetic reasons**.

I would say:

> 「ウォルマート**で**リンゴをさがしたほうがいい。」

FYI, the verbs that take 「に」 as their usual location-marker include:

住{す}む (to live)、いる (to be, to exit)、滞在{たいざい}する (to stay), etc.  These are all ***stative*** verbs.

「探{さが}す」 ("to look for") is too "active" an action to take 「に」 except for the special cases explained above.